# How to update table that has UPDATE trigger within INSERT trigger in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, sql-update, database-trigger

I have a table `mytable` with column `myorder`, where I store order of records. I need a behaviour, where inserting a new record with existing `myorder` value will increment all records having greater `myorder` by 1. Same behaviour should be in place when updating a row with existing `myorder` value.

I’ve made a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger where I update those values, but it gives me an error

`ERROR: tuple to be updated was already modified by an operation triggered by the current command`

Seems like it’s recursively firing triggers for every updated row in an uncontrolled order. `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` won’t work, because it'll violate unique constraint on that column or end up with infinite loop.
Is there an effective way to implement such a behaviour? Here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  myorder INTEGER NOT NULL,
  myotherstuff TEXT,
  CONSTRAINT unq_myorder UNIQUE (myorder) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reorder_records ()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $function$
DECLARE
  reorder BOOLEAN := TRUE;
BEGIN

  RAISE NOTICE 'fired on %', NEW.myorder;

  reorder := EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE myorder = NEW.myorder);

  IF reorder THEN
    UPDATE
      mytable
    SET
      myorder = myorder + 1
    WHERE
      myorder >= NEW.myorder;
  END IF;

RETURN NEW; 
END;
$function$;


CREATE TRIGGER trg_reorder
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE bak.reorder_records();

INSERT INTO mytable (myorder, myotherstuff) VALUES
  (1, 'one')
 ,(2, 'two')
 ,(3, 'three');

--THIS ONE FAILS!!!

INSERT INTO mytable (myorder, myotherstuff) VALUES
  (2, 'four');
```

Comment: So, the expected output should be `(1, 'one'), (2, 'four'), (3, 'two'), (4, 'three')` after inserting? And this re-ordering should work when update-ing too? Is it a problem if (during an update) the old `myorder` value will leave a gap?

Comment: One solution I can think of is that update only the next `myorder` in the trigger & let that cascade through the table. Something like `UPDATE mytable SET myorder = myorder + 1 WHERE myorder = (SELECT MIN(myorder) FROM mytable WHERE myorder >= NEW.myorder)` -- It wouldn't perform very well though.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to ignore update trigger when update is invoked by insert trigger by passing arguments somehow? Shifting ID's seems like a common task, but I can't find a simple and elegant solution for it.